# Why "No such file or directory" in pyomo when using ipopt solver?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ampl, pyomo

When I am running a very simple problem, I occasionally get this error from the `ipopt` solver:  `No such file or directory: '/var/folders/4f/z25gj3_d29b45_2nx87p8rvr0000gn/T/tmpwMeEAK.pyomo.sol'`.   This time I see it, I really want to figure out why this is the case.

Here is my model with very basic constraints and objective function:

```
cm=ConcreteModel()

a = Var([1,2], [0,1,2,3], domain=Reals)
b = Var([1,2], [0,1,2,3], domain=Reals)
c = Var([0,1,2,3], domain=Reals)

cm.q = a
cm.p = b
cm.u = c

cm.end_a_1 = Constraint(expr=(a[1,3] == 1.0))
cm.end_b_2 = Constraint(expr=(b[2,3] == 0.0))
cm.end_a_2 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,3] == 1.0))
cm.start_a_2 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,0] == 0.0))
cm.start_a_1 = Constraint(expr=(a[1,0] == 1.0))
cm.start_b_2 = Constraint(expr=(b[2,0] == -11.0))
cm.start_b_1 = Constraint(expr=(b[1,0] == -11.0))
cm.end_b_1 = Constraint(expr=(b[1,3] == 0.0))
cm.constr_a_1_1 = Constraint(expr=a[1,2] == a[1,1] + a[2,1])
cm.constr_a_1_0 = Constraint(expr=a[1,1] == a[1,0] + a[2,0])
cm.constr_b_1_0 = Constraint(expr=(b[1,1] == (b[1,0] + -(b[2,0]))))
cm.constr_b_1_1 = Constraint(expr=(b[1,2] == (b[1,1] + -(b[2,1]))))
cm.constr_b_1_2 = Constraint(expr=(b[1,3] == (b[1,2] + -(b[2,2]))))
cm.constr_b_2_2 = Constraint(expr=(b[2,3] == (b[2,2] + -(b[1,2]))))
cm.constr_b_2_1 = Constraint(expr=(b[2,2] == (b[2,1] + -(b[1,1]))))
cm.constr_b_2_0 = Constraint(expr=(b[2,1] == (b[2,0] + -(b[1,0]))))
cm.constr_a_2_2 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,3] == (a[2,2] + a[1,2])))
cm.constr_a_2_0 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,1] == (a[2,0] + a[1,0])))
cm.constr_a_2_1 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,2] == (a[2,1] + a[1,1])))
cm.constr_a_1_2 = Constraint(expr=(a[1,3] == (a[1,2] + a[2,2])))

oe=c[0]
o = Objective(expr=oe)
cm.objective=o
cm_results = SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(cm)
```

And of course when I solve the above problem I get a traceback with:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyomo/opt/plugins/sol.pyc in __call__(self, filename, res, soln, suffixes)
     44         """
     45         try:
---> 46             with open(filename,"r") as f:
     47                 return self._load(f, res, soln, suffixes)
     48         except ValueError as e:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/4f/z25gj3_d29b45_2nx87p8rvr0000gn/T/tmpwMeEAK.pyomo.sol'
```

Now, what is really weird about this, is when I take out the last three constraints (i.e. commented out):

```
# cm.constr_a_2_0 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,1] == (a[2,0] + a[1,0])))
# cm.constr_a_2_1 = Constraint(expr=(a[2,2] == (a[2,1] + a[1,1])))
# cm.constr_a_1_2 = Constraint(expr=(a[1,3] == (a[1,2] + a[2,2])))
```

Then there are no problems with the solver.

What is causing this error?  And why does it get solved when those last few constraints are removed?

Answer (score 2):

I did not use that lib for a long time, but a short remark:

Your error indicates (in my interpretation), that no solution was found (the `.sol` suffix is used for solutions). To be more precise: **the solver thinks that there is no feasible solution** (and no valid output file will be generated). Without checking your problem, adding / removing constraints can have this effect in general in regards to feasibility.

The basic question in regards to usage is: why is this pretty normal status so obfuscated? To me it seems, that you are using the lib wrongly. **You should not read out the solution before checking there is one!** You are doing this implicitly with `cm_results = SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(cm)`.
But as i did not use it for a long time (because of better alternatives in the convex-world; but yeah, good interfaces of ipopt are rare), i can't show you code. But i remember there were some examples within the official blog or at least some user-forum / mailing-list about status-checking before output-reading!

Apart from that: i think there is also a log-file you can read out to strenghten my thoughts (probably something like: "problem is infeasible" in there; basically there are 3 files involded each time: input, output, log).

Comment: Thank you @sascha! Where do I find this log file?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of exit from Ipopt is indicative of an internal error during the solve (probably does not have to do with feasibility). The latest release of Pyomo (5.2) has been updated to handle this case better. If you add `tee=True` to the `solve()` call, it will stream the Ipopt output and you should get more information.

Also, one should always check the solve status before using the solution. When I'm being lazy, I typically do something like:

```
ipopt = SolverFactory("ipopt")
result = ipopt.solve(model)
assert str(result.solver.status) == "ok"
assert str(result.solver.termination_condition) == "optimal"
```

You can modify this to handle different exit conditions.

Comment: OKay, I will try that.  Very strange that `pyomo` would have such an internal error...it could be a bug.  Are there alternative solvers in python so that I can avoid things like this?

Comment: It is not an internal error in Pyomo. This happens in the external solver that Pyomo sends your model to. With Ipopt, often times this has to do with a bad initial starting point or an iterate where the solver attempts to evaluate the derivative of a function at a point where it is not differentiable (e.g., sqrt(0)). There are usually ways to model around this.

Comment: There are plenty of other solvers you can interface to with Pyomo, you just have to install them on your machine. It looks like your model is linear, so GLPK would be one option (that is free). You just have to make sure the glpsol executable is in your PATH (which it seems like you have already done for Ipopt).

Comment: The problems I solve are for control theory, and they are generally non linear.  Usually the objective functions are Hamiltonian functions, or some type of polynomial.  Any solver you would recommend for that?  The new version of pyomo (`5.2.1`) did not seem to help this.

Comment: I just did what I recommended that you do (add tee=True) and Ipopt printed a pretty clear error message. Your problem has too few degrees of freedom (more equality constraints than there are variables).